# Android BottomNavigationVIew overlap fragment content

Tags: android, android-fragments

Im trying to do a chat. **`MainActivity`** has a **`ToolBar`** and **`BottomNavigationVIew`**.

The chat `fragment` has a `recyclerView`, an `editText` and `ImageButton`, but when I load the fragment the `BottomNavigationVIew` overlaps the `EditText` and the `ImageButton`

I dont know if this is important but in Android Studio the item of `BottomNavigationVIew` looks smaller than it is, not for example like the ToolBar
Also I use `android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"` and it doesn't work
[image]

[image]

I have tried many ways but I cant do it

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_home"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_parent_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/parent_name"
                android:textSize="20sp" />


            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/student_photo"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/foto"
                app:civ_border_color="@color/iron"
                app:civ_border_width="1dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/navigation">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pb_loading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/primary_dark"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_state_list"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_state_list"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

chat_fragment.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/messages"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message_input"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_message"
        android:imeActionId="@+id/send"
        android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_send"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/send_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
        android:contentDescription="@string/action_send"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment.java

```
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, chat);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `activity_main.xml`, make your root layout `LinearLayout` with orientation set to vertical. Remove the `LinearLayout` right inside root layout. And set the following height-width config for your `FrameLayout`:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Finally, remove all `align...` stuff, because they don't work inside `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Thanks mate. Setting android:layout_height to 0 resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You must move your FrameLayout code out of LinearLayout(i mean after LinearLayout), and also you must add this code to your frame:

```
    android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
```